# Filter Dataframe on columns defined in a list

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe
df

```
+----------+----+----+----+---+---+----+---+---+-------+-------+
|      WEEK|DIM1|DIM2|  T1| T2| T3|  T1| T2| T3|T1_diff|T2_diff|
+----------+----+----+----+---+---+----+---+---+-------+-------+
|2016-04-02|  14|NULL|9874|880| 23|9879|820| 45|     -5|     60|
|2016-04-30|  14|  FR|9875| 13| 34|9785|  9| 67|     90|      4|
+----------+----+----+----+---+---+----+---+---+-------+-------+
```

I want to do two things on this data frame:

1. Select only WEEK, DIM1, DIM2, T1_diff, T2_diff
2. Filter T1_diff or T2_diff > 3

I am currently doing it like this -

```
val selectColumns = Seq("WEEK", "DIM1", "DIM2","T1_diff","T2_diff")
df.select(selectColumns.head, selectColumns.tail: _*).filter($"T1_diff" > 3 or $"T2_diff" > 3).show()
```

I have a use case, where i have my targetColumns defined like this -

```
val targetColumns = Seq("T1_diff", "T2_diff")
```

I need to use the above sequence to apply it in the filter. This is in sequence, because more columns can be added in targetColumns list. 
I tried something like this -

```
df.filter(r => !targetColumns.map(x => col(x) > 3).isEmpty).show()
```

This doesnt seem to work. Can anyone tell me what is the best way to do this ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `reduce` on the sequence of target columns after you've mapped each of them into a condition (`col(name) > 3`), using `or` to "merge" them together into one condition:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val selectColumns = Seq("id", "type", "DIM2","T1_diff","T2_diff")
val targetColumns = Seq("T1_diff", "T2_diff")

df.select(selectColumns.head, selectColumns.tail: _*)
  .filter(targetColumns.map(name => col(name) > 3).reduce(_ or _))
  .show()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a String using `targetColumns` `List` and then pass that String to `where` function.

```
val targetColumns = List("T1_diff", "T2_diff")
val selectColumns = Seq("WEEK", "DIM1", "DIM2", "T1_diff", "T2_diff")

//create the where condition to filter the columns
val condition = targetColumns.map(c => s"$c>3").mkString(" OR ")

//select the columns and apply filter using where function.
df.select(selectColumns.head, selectColumns.tail: _*).where(condition).show(false)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can simply do the following making a `string query`

```
val targetColumns = Seq("T1_diff", "T2_diff")

df.filter(targetColumns.map(x => s"$x > 3").mkString(" or ")).show()
```

and you can add as many columns in `targetColumns` as you want